# Create 2 column from single column based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table having 4 values id, qty, value and refernceid 
Values  are

```
Id  qty   value refid
1   100     100    0
2  -100    -100    1
3   100     100    0
4   -40     -40    3
5   -30     -30    3
```

Now i want to separate in two column qty n value on the basis of refid

Comment: You sure you have entered the correct data. Negative quantity which is also equal to value. Also, share the desired output.

Comment: Ummm....what is the question? This might be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/